# If a group algebra acts regularly on a module, can this module be identified as a left ideal?

Tags: representation-theory, group-rings

To be more specific, I am looking at $F_2[D_p]$, where $D_p$ is the dihedral group of order $2p$.

If this group acts regularly on the basis of a vector space $F_2^{2p}$, and there is a subspace of $F_2^{2p}$ that is fixed under the action of the group, is it true that this subspace can be identified with a left ideal of $F_2[D_p]$?  I guess the idea is that you can identify each basis element of $F_2^{2p}$ with an element in $D_p$.  But is it guaranteed we can do that as long as the action is regular?

Besides, it kinda bothers me that $F_2[D_p]$ is not semi-simple, since the characteristic (which is 2) divides the order of $D_p$.  This ring doesn't decompose.

Comment: What do you mean by "regular"?  If you mean that the group $D_p$ acts regularly on a basis, then that vector space is isomorphic to $F_2[D_p]$ by the definition of a regular action.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean by regular.  And I actually meant a subspace of $F_2^{2p}$ (corrected in the questions).   So does that mean this space is equivalent to a left ideal of the group ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the action is regular gives an equivariant isomorphism $F_2^{2p}\cong F_2[D_p]$.  This isomorphism sends your invariant subspace to an invariant subspace (under left multiplication) of $F_2[D_p]$. That is, a left ideal.  So, yes.

Comment: I don't understand why they are isomorphic...  Is there a way to explicitly construct the isomorphism?

Comment: You send 1 to any one of the basis vectors; there's a unique equivariant extension.

Comment: Yes, I figured that later.  Thanks for your help!